# How to extract JSON Array From json in mulesoft

Tags: web-services, mule, anypoint-studio

I am getting xml output then i am converting that xml into json object.the format is given below.

```
{
"SOAP-ENV:Envelope": {
    "@xmlns:SOAP-ENV": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "@xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "SOAP-ENV:Body": {
        "rpc:TestExampleResponse": {
            "@xmlns:rpc": "http://Test.com/asi/",
            "TestMessage": {
                "listOfTESTS": {
                    "@xmlns:xmlns": "http://www.Test.com/xml/TEST",
                    "TESTS": [{
                            "id": "1",
                            "lastSyncDate": "12/16/2015 07:06:38",
                            "listOfTESTsyncrealtimeChild": null
                        }, {
                            "id": "2",
                            "lastSyncDate": "12/16/2015 07:06:38",
                            "listOfTESTsyncrealtimeChild": null
                        }

                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

i want to extract Test array from JSON Output in Mulesoft.I dont know how to extract that array in mulesoft.Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried Xpath but getting the following error Execution of the expression "xpath3('/SOAP-ENV:Envelope',payload,'STRING')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String

Comment: You can't use XPATH because the payload at hand is not of XML. You can find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647518/how-to-extract-json-array-from-json-in-mulesoft/34649584#34649584) useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Dataweave** (Transform Message component in Anypoint Studio)

**(Mule EE)**

Take a look to the documentation:

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-dataweave-in-studio

Sample script for your input:

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
TESTS: payload."SOAP-ENV:Envelope"."SOAP-ENV:Body"."rpc:TestExampleResponse".TestMessage.listOfTESTS.TESTS map ((tEST , indexOfTEST) -> {
        id: tEST.id,
        lastSyncDate: tEST.lastSyncDate,
        listOfTESTsyncrealtimeChild: tEST.listOfTESTsyncrealtimeChild
})
```

Output when using `%output application/json`:

```
{
  "TESTS": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "lastSyncDate": "12/16/2015 07:06:38",
      "listOfTESTsyncrealtimeChild": null
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "lastSyncDate": "12/16/2015 07:06:38",
      "listOfTESTsyncrealtimeChild": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Output when using `%output application/java`:

```
{TESTS=[{id=1, lastSyncDate=12/16/2015 07:06:38, listOfTESTsyncrealtimeChild=null}, {id=2, lastSyncDate=12/16/2015 07:06:38, listOfTESTsyncrealtimeChild=null}]}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can write a custom transformer like below. This transformer uses `Jackson (com.fasterxml.jackson)` dependency.

The transformer returns a list of strings where each string represents an element of your `TESTS` array.

```
public class JsonArrayExtractor extends AbstractTransformer {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final String testsNodeJsonPointer = "/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/rpc:TestExampleResponse/TestMessage/listOfTESTS/TESTS";

    public JsonArrayExtractor() {
        registerSourceType(DataTypeFactory.STRING);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc) throws TransformerException {
        String payload = Objects.toString(src);

        JsonNode root;
        try {
            root = mapper.readTree(payload);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new TransformerException(this, e);
        }

        List<String> testsList = new ArrayList<>();

        JsonNode testsNode = root.at(JsonPointer.valueOf(testsNodeJsonPointer));
        if (testsNode instanceof ArrayNode) {
            ArrayNode testsArrayNode = (ArrayNode) testsNode;
            for (JsonNode test : testsArrayNode) {
                testsList.add(test.toString());
            }
        }
        return testsList;
    }
}
```

And you can use the above transformer in your flow as below.

```
<custom-transformer class="org.ram.JsonArrayExtractor" doc:name="extractTestsArray"/>
```